# Injective homomorphism 3

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $F$ is a field and $h:F \to R$ is a homomorphism, where $R$ is not equal to $\{0\}$.

Show $h$ is injective.

I am not sure wether proving if $h(a)=h(b)$ then $a=b$, or that $\ker(h)=\{0\}$ will be easier.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please check, for future reference, the editing I have done to your question. $\LaTeX$ is the language of choice for writing Math here - just pick it up from the other questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

The second one, as a field $F$ has no ideals besides $\{ 0 \}$ and $F$ itself.

I assume your rings are unital, and that homomorphisms take $1$ to $1$, otherwise $h$ might well be the map taking everyting to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $h(x)=0$ for some $x \in F^*$, then for any $y \in F$,  $h(y) = h(yxx^{-1}) = h(y)h(x)h(x^{-1}) = 0$. Thus we get that either $h =0$ or $h$ is injective. Since we usually define a homomorphism with the property that $h(1)=1$ we get that $h \not = 0$, so $h$ is injective.